# Aggregate and group bookings

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables which I am trying to aggregate data using T-SQL.
Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE rooms (
    room_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    room_name varchar(50)
);

CREATE TABLE bookings (
    id int NOT NULL,
    account_id int,
    room_id int,
    booking_timestamp datetime,
);
```

Data:

```
INSERT INTO rooms (room_id, room_name)
  VALUES ('1', 'Suite A'), 
  ('2', 'Suite B'),
  ('3', 'Suite C'),
  ('4', 'Suite D'),
  ('5', 'Suite X');

INSERT INTO bookings (id, account_id, room_id, booking_timestamp)
  VALUES ('1', '123', '1', '2018-12-21 10:00:00'),
  ('1',  '123', '1'), '2018-12-21 10:00:00', 
  ('2',  '123', '1', '2018-12-20 10:00:00'),
  ('3',  '123', '1', '2018-12-19 10:00:00'),
  ('4',  '123', '1', '2018-12-18 10:00:00'),
  ('5',  '123', '2', '2018-12-17 10:00:00'),
  ('6',  '123', '3', '2018-12-16 10:00:00'),
  ('7',  '123', '4', '2018-12-15 10:00:00'),
  ('8',  '123', '4', '2018-12-14 10:00:00'),
  ('9',  '123', '5', '2018-12-14 10:00:00'),
  ('10', '123', '1', '2018-12-13 10:00:00'),
  ('11', '124', '4', '2018-12-21 10:00:00'),
  ('12', '124', '5', '2018-12-22 10:00:00'),
  ('13', '124', '1', '2018-12-23 10:00:00'),
  ('14', '124', '1', '2018-12-24 10:00:00');
```

Query:

```
SELECT ar.room_id, ar.cnt as number_of_bookings
  FROM (SELECT room_id, count(*) AS cnt, 
             row_number() over (
               partition by room_id order by count(*) desc,
             max(booking_timestamp) desc) AS seqnum
          FROM bookings
            WHERE booking_timestamp >= '2018-01-01'
          GROUP BY room_id, id
       ) ar
    WHERE seqnum = 1
```

Now notice in my data the id's for the bookings table are not unique, there could be multiple instances of the same id (just with a different date).

The query I am using doesn't seem to product the right results of I group by the `id` as well. When I only use `room_id` they work fine.

Can someone advise what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit: Desired Result**

> ```
> account_id | most booked room | count
> 123        | Suite A          | 5
> 124        | Suite A          | 2
> ```

Comment: what is your desired result?

Comment: Sorry, updated original question.

Comment: You didn't fill the booking_timestamp field.

Comment: @forpas you are right, I have updated the sample data accordingly, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Your desired result makes me believe you're after the room an account booked the most. That means you have to partition by the account not the room.

```
SELECT x.account_id,
       r.room_name "most booked room",
       x.count
       FROM (SELECT b.account_id,
                    b.room_id,
                    count(*) count,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY b.account_id
                                       ORDER BY count(*) DESC) rownumber
                    FROM bookings b
                    WHERE b.booking_timestamp >= '2018-01-01'
                    GROUP BY b.account_id,
                             b.room_id) x
            LEFT JOIN rooms r
                      ON r.room_id = x.room_id
       WHERE x.rownumber = 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8dc77f59f6af8f5361a7ee82a3cb28cd) (Note: This is MySQL 8.0 as `AUTO_INCREMENT` is a MySQL thing, not an SQL Server thing as the T-SQL tag implied. But the query should work for SQL Server too.)

Answer (score 0):

Long way of divide and conquer:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    select account_id, r.room_name, count(*) as cnt
    from bookings b
    inner join rooms r on b.room_id = r.room_id
    group by account_id, r.room_name
)
,cte2 AS
(
    select *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY cnt DESC) rn
    from cte
)

select account_id, room_name as most_booked_room, cnt as [count] 
from cte2
where rn = 1
```

From your desired result, I assume that you want to see which account used which room the most. So you need to group by  all your numbers by account_id, room_id. But in partition by clause, you need to partition it by account_id only since you are trying to rank numbers within a single account, not within a single account and single room.

Here is how your original query will look:

```
select account_id, room_id, cnt from 
(
    SELECT account_id, room_id, count(*) AS cnt, 
            row_number() over (partition by account_id order by count(*) desc, max(booking_timestamp) desc) AS seqnum
    FROM bookings
    WHERE booking_timestamp >= '2018-01-01'
    GROUP BY account_id, room_id
) a
WHERE seqnum = 1
```

But I prefer divide and conquer, yes it is more typing but also more readable and maintainable if it needs some tweaking in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it.

```
    ----drop table rooms   drop table bookings
CREATE TABLE rooms (
    room_id int NOT NULL ,
    room_name varchar(50)
);

CREATE TABLE bookings (
    id int NOT NULL,
    account_id int,
    room_id int,
    booking_timestamp datetime,
);
INSERT INTO rooms (room_id, room_name)
  VALUES ('1', 'Suite A'), 
  ('2', 'Suite B'),
  ('3', 'Suite C'),
  ('4', 'Suite D'),
  ('5', 'Suite X');

INSERT INTO bookings (id, account_id, room_id, booking_timestamp)
  VALUES ('1', '123', '1', '2018-12-21 10:00:00'),
  ('1',  '123', '1', '2018-12-21 10:00:00'), 
  ('2',  '123', '1', '2018-12-20 10:00:00'),
  ('3',  '123', '1', '2018-12-19 10:00:00'),
  ('4',  '123', '1', '2018-12-18 10:00:00'),
  ('5',  '123', '2', '2018-12-17 10:00:00'),
  ('6',  '123', '3', '2018-12-16 10:00:00'),
  ('7',  '123', '4', '2018-12-15 10:00:00'),
  ('8',  '123', '4', '2018-12-14 10:00:00'),
  ('9',  '123', '5', '2018-12-14 10:00:00'),
  ('10', '123', '1', '2018-12-13 10:00:00'),
  ('11', '124', '4', '2018-12-21 10:00:00'),
  ('12', '124', '5', '2018-12-22 10:00:00'),
  ('13', '124', '1', '2018-12-23 10:00:00'),
  ('14', '124', '1', '2018-12-24 10:00:00');

 ;with cte as (
select a.room_id,a.room_name,b.account_id,
count(*)over(partition by b.account_id,b.room_id) as count ,
row_number()over(partition by b.account_id order by (select 1)) as rn 
from rooms a 
join bookings b on a.room_id=b.room_id)
select account_id,room_name,count   from cte where rn=1
/*
account_id  room_name                                          count
----------- -------------------------------------------------- -----------
123         Suite A                                            6
124         Suite A                                            2
*/
```